# How to get all elements of same name from same level in xmlstreamreader?

Tags: java, xml, xmlstreamreader

I have an xml file which goes like :

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <b>
      </b>
    </c>
  </b>
  <b>
    ...
  </b>
</a>
```

to parse it I wrote a code like :

```
XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml);

//advanced to b element
while(xsr.hasNext()) {
    if(xsr.isStartElement() && "b".equals(xsr.getLocalName())) {
        System.out.println(xsr.getLocalName());
    }
    xsr.next();
}
```

My problem is this even matches child element b under c element, I only want to get elements b which are direct child of a element and I want to pass it to method which perform functionality over it. Can anyone guide me on how to achieve it?

Comment: Have you looked into using XPath?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Let me look over it.